# Italian term for a country road

Tags: translation

Which is the Italian term or expression for a country road that goes nowhere just visits the properties along the road?

*Strada senza uscita* does not quite fit.

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE! Could you please add more context? _Strada senza uscita_ doens't fit which situation?

Comment: I just have in mind that there is a special word describing a country road that gives access to the fields and properties along the road but does not go anywhere else and I cannot remember what that word is.

Answer (score 5):

If I correctly catch the meaning of your question, the correct expression would be *strada di campagna*, but in Italian we have also other and expressions to define country roads.

For example other variants of strada di campagna (depending on the size and road surface) are (in brackets my own translation attempt):

- [carrareccia](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ricerca/carrareccia/): Strada campestre che può essere percorsa da carri; (Country road that can be traveled by carts)
- [mulattiera](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mulattiera): Strada o sentiero di montagna costruiti in modo da dare adito al passaggio delle carovane di muli o di altre bestie da soma; (Road or pathway built in order to allow the passage of mule trains or other beasts of burden)
- [tratturo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tratturo1/): Larga pista con fondo naturale segnata dalle greggi nel loro periodico spostarsi, di solito con lunghi tratti rettilinei; il termine è particolarmente usato per le piste che univano l’Appennino abruzzese alle pianure della Puglia e della Calabria; (Large track with natural road surface flock of sheep in their periodic shift, usually with long stretches of road.)
- [viottolo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/viottolo/): Sentiero, stradina di campagna o di montagna; (Pathway, country road or mountain road)
- [sentiero](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sentiero/): Via a fondo naturale tracciata in luoghi montani e campestri, in boschi e prati, dal passaggio di uomini e animali (Path with natural road surface traced in country or mountain places, in the woods or in the fields, by the passage of men and animals)

Looking at the various variants of [strada](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/strada) on Treccani dictionary, you can also find more specific definitions:

- s. vicinali: quelle costruite da un proprietario di un fondo rustico e che fanno parte del fondo stesso per uso esclusivo del proprietario o, soltanto in caso di servitù, di terze persone; (roads built by the owner of a property in the country where the owner has exclusive use of them, or only in case of servitude, the use is extended to other people)

Comment: Some of these refer to roads that go from a point A to a point B, though, while apparently the OP's question seem to refer to a road that “goes nowhere” (even though it's not clear to me who would build such a road...). _Viottolo_, _sentiero_ and _strada vicinale_ seem the closest ones.

Comment: Actually you're right about the fact that nobody would build a road that goes nowhere. Besided _strada senza uscita_ or _vicolo cieco_ wouldn't fit... Strada di campagna o sentiero would remain my best bet trying to be generic.

Comment: Would 'contrada' be correct for a road that is used to access the properties along it but does not connect to other centers of population?

Comment: @pabrereton I don’t think contrada refers to a road but rather to a region or a pet of a village. At least according to Treccani’s definition.

Comment: @pabrereton I don't think there's a special name for that kind of country road, as opposed to generic name for country roads. *Contrada* is the name of a region (typically, but not exclusively, of a medieval city neighborhood), not of a road.

Comment: Anche *capezzagna o cavedagna* - Strada di accesso in terra battuta che corre lungo le testate dei campi. Hoepli

Comment: Thanks to everyone who commented. I think s. vicinali bet fits what I had in mind.